# how to use WalletConnect (https://walletconnect.com) with MeshJs (https://meshjs.dev/) cardano development library

Tags: next.js, blockchain, wallet-connect, cardano

wallet connector easily supports cardano-serialization-lib but i am not getting any way to use it with MeshJS.
As meshJs only provides BroserWallets.enable(_) function only to connect wallet , how to use it with WalletConnector